# How to processing an image downloaded from AWS S3 with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, image-processing, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I want download an image from AWS S3 and process it with php. I am using "imagecreatefromjpeg" and "getimagesize"  to process my image but it seem that

Storage::disk('s3')->get(imageUrlonS3);

retrieve the image in binary and is giving me errors. This is my code:

```
function createSlices($imagePath) {

                //create transform driver object
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
                $sizeArray = getimagesize($imagePath);

                //Set the Image dimensions
                $imageWidth = $sizeArray[0];
                $imageHeight = $sizeArray[1];

                //See how many zoom levels are required for the width and height
                $widthLog = ceil(log($imageWidth/256,2));
                $heightLog = ceil(log($imageHeight/256,2));


                //more code here to slice the image
                .
                .
                .
                .
            }

            // ex: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/image.jpg
            $content = Storage::disk('s3')->get(imageUrlonS3);
            createSlices($content);
```

What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the exact errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right in your question what the problem is - the `get` method returns the source of the image of itself, not the location of the image. When you pass that to `createSlices`, you're passing the binary data, not its file path. Inside of `createSlices` you call `imagecreatefromjpeg`, which expects a file path, not the image itself.

If this indeed the case, you should be able to use `createimagefromstring` instead of `createimagefromjpeg` and `getimagesizefromstring` instead of `getimagesize`. The functions `createimagefromstring` and `getimagesizefromstring` each expects the binary string of the image, which I believe is what you have.

Here's the relevant documentation:

`createimagefromstring` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

`getimagesizefromstring` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php

Resulting code might look something like this:

```
function createSlices($imageData) {
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
    $sizeArray = getimagesizefromstring($imageData);

    //Everything else can probably be the same
    .
    .
    .
    .
}

$contents = Storage::disk('s3')->get($imageUrlOnS3);
createSlices($contents);
```

Please note I haven't tested this, but I believe from what I can see in your question and what I read in the documentation that this might just do it.